# MySQL fails to start [InnoDB Repair]

Tags: mysql, data-recovery, innodb

After inspecting the log files I see that some of the databases have errors.

```
2017-05-16 08:52:48 7fc0cb8abb00  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140466025315072 in file ha_innodb.cc line 21990
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
170516  8:52:48 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.23-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=8
max_threads=10002
thread_count=8
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 22100835 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fb8d3fd1008
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7fc0cb8ab0b0 thread_stack 0x48400
2017-05-16  8:52:48 140466025618176 [ERROR] InnoDB:  InnoDB: Unable to allocate memory of size 18446744073709545072.

2017-05-16 08:52:48 7fc0cb8f5b00  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140466025618176 in file ha_innodb.cc line 21990
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

InnoDB recovery is set to 3 but I don't understand why it wants to allocate that much memory to recover a database!

Comment: Could you share your mysql config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had this issue before and followed [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20170529105215/http://chepri.com/our-blog/mysql-innodb-corruption-and-recovery/) to solve it:

Steps to get it back up.

1. Stop mysqld.
2. Backup /var/lib/mysql/ib*
3. Add the following line into /etc/my.cnf

`innodb_force_recovery = 4`

4. Restart mysqld.
5. Dump all tables: `$ mysqldump -A > dump.sql`
6. Drop all databases which need recovery.
7. Stop mysqld.
8. Remove /var/lib/mysql/ib*
9. Comment out innodb_force_recovery in /etc/my.cnf
10. Restart mysqld. Look at mysql error log. By default it should be /var/lib/mysql/server/hostname.com.err to see how it creates new ib* files.
11. Restore databases from the dump:mysql < dump.sql

**Hint:** A simple query for finding all of your InnoDB tables in case you want to specifically target the corruption.

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE engine = 'innodb';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! after wasting 3 days this article got me the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: There is a saying here: always post solution, linked pages or blogs go down pretty fast..